# Swift Custom UIView Inherited by UILabel

Tags: swift, inheritance, uiview

I have an inheritance problem that I'm trying to solve. Typically, I'd just use multi-inheritance here, but Swift doesn't really do that.

Custom UIView

```
import UIKit

class ValidationView: UIView {

    var required:Bool = false
    var validRegex:String? = nil

    var requiredLbl:UILabel?

    private var requiredColor:UIColor = UIColor.red
    private var requiredText:String = "*"
    private var requiredFont:UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupValidationViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupValidationViews()
    }

    private func setupValidationViews() {
        self.requiredLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 30, y: 30, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.styleRequiredLabel()
        self.addSubview(self.requiredLbl!)
    }

    func styleRequiredLabel(color:UIColor?, text:String?, font:UIFont?) {
        self.requiredColor = color ?? self.requiredColor
        self.requiredText = text ?? self.requiredText
        self.requiredFont = font ?? self.requiredFont
        self.styleRequiredLabel()
    }

    private func styleRequiredLabel() {
        self.requiredLbl?.textColor = self.requiredColor
        self.requiredLbl?.text = self.requiredText
        self.requiredLbl?.font = self.requiredFont
    }

}
```

Custom UITextField

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable open class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

}
```

I want that Custom UITextField to also be a ValidationView. I know I could do a protocol and extension and then have my CustomTextField implement that protocol, but that doesn't allow for init overrides. I'd rather not have to change the inits on ever view that implements ValidationView.

Something like this can be accomplished using @arturdev answer. I ended up with this:

```
import UIKit

class ValidatableProperties {
    var required:Bool
    var validRegex:String?
    var requiredColor:UIColor
    var requiredText:String
    var requiredFont:UIFont

    init(required:Bool, validRegex:String?, requiredColor:UIColor, requiredText:String, requiredFont:UIFont) {
        self.required = required
        self.validRegex = validRegex
        self.requiredText = requiredText
        self.requiredColor = requiredColor
        self.requiredFont = requiredFont
    }
}

protocol Validatable : UIView {

    var validatableProperties:ValidatableProperties! { get set }
    var requiredLbl:UILabel! { get set }

    func setupValidationDefaults()
    func setupValidationViews(frame:CGRect)
    func styleRequiredLabel(color:UIColor?, text:String?, font:UIFont?)

}

extension Validatable {

    func setupValidationDefaults() {
        let props = ValidatableProperties(required: false, validRegex: nil, requiredColor: UIColor.red, requiredText: "*", requiredFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .bold))
        self.validatableProperties = props
    }

    func setupValidationViews(frame:CGRect) {
        self.requiredLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.styleRequiredLabel()
        self.addSubview(self.requiredLbl)
    }

    func styleRequiredLabel(color:UIColor?, text:String?, font:UIFont?) {
        self.validatableProperties.requiredColor = color ?? self.validatableProperties.requiredColor
        self.validatableProperties.requiredText = text ?? self.validatableProperties.requiredText
        self.validatableProperties.requiredFont = font ?? self.validatableProperties.requiredFont
        self.styleRequiredLabel()
    }

    private func styleRequiredLabel() {
        self.requiredLbl.textColor = self.validatableProperties.requiredColor
        self.requiredLbl.text = self.validatableProperties.requiredText
        self.requiredLbl.font = self.validatableProperties.requiredFont
    }

}

open class ValidationTextField:UITextField, Validatable {
    var requiredLbl: UILabel!
    var validatableProperties: ValidatableProperties!


    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupValidationDefaults()
        self.setupValidationViews(frame: frame)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupValidationDefaults()
        self.setupValidationViews(frame: self.frame)
    }

}
```

But this requires extending all classes you want validatable into their own custom classes, needing to overwrite the inits every time and call the methods. It works, but it's not ideal and, while not exactly anti-pattern inheritance, certainly has some code-smell to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `ValidationView` as protocol instead of class, and conform your custom classes to that protocol.

> ValidatableView.swift

```
import UIKit

fileprivate var requiredColor = UIColor.red
fileprivate var requiredText  = "*"
fileprivate var requiredFont  = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)

fileprivate struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var lblKey = "_lblKey_"
}

protocol ValidatableView: class {
    var required: Bool {get}
    var validRegex: String? {get}
    var requiredLbl: UILabel? {get}
}

extension ValidatableView where Self: UIView {
    var required: Bool {
        return false
    }

    var validRegex: String? {
        return nil
    }

    var requiredLbl: UILabel? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.lblKey) as? UILabel
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.lblKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    func setupValidation() {
        self.requiredLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 30, y: 30, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.requiredLbl?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        self.styleRequiredLabel()
        self.addSubview(self.requiredLbl!)
    }

    func styleRequiredLabel(color:UIColor? = requiredColor, text:String? = requiredText, font:UIFont? = requiredFont) {
        self.requiredLbl?.textColor = requiredColor
        self.requiredLbl?.text = requiredText
        self.requiredLbl?.font = requiredFont
    }
}
```

> CustomTextField.swift

```
@IBDesignable open class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupValidation()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupValidation()
    }
}

extension CustomTextField: ValidatableView { //<- Magic line :)

}
```

Comment: I have something similar to this now, but I'm curious about this line in particular: `extension ValidatableView where Self: UIView` Can that have multiple where clauses? like, could I have this fill default functionality for 3 or 4 where clauses then fall through to a different extension if the where clauses don't match?

Comment: For better clarifications here
`protocol Validatable : UIView { //protocol stuff }`
`extension Validatable where Self: UITextField || Self: UITextView || Self: UISwitch { //validation functionality }`
`extension Validatable { //fall through for non-included views }`
`extension UIView : Validatable { //override inits and other methods to make validatable }`

Comment: Not implicitly, but explicitly yes. But you don’t need that, cause all the mentioned classes are inherited from UIView already, and this extension will be applied only on those classes who conforms to that protocol

Comment: I've adjusted my OP to better explain my catch here. I have a setup going following similar to what you've said, but it still mean I need a few lines of code and two overwritten inits for any view type that should be validatable. What I'd prefer, is to have a more generic UIView based thing so I don't have to overwrite those inits every time. This does get to a working solution though, just not 100% there on my clean scale. Maybe like 90% there though.

Comment: Well, if you don’t want to write that boilerplate code in every custom class, you can swizzle the ‘didMoveToSuperView’ method in the extension, and call the setup method there.

Comment: How would I do that? I was under the impression that extensions can't do any overriding of super methods.

Comment: The other issue is that I have to declare requiredLbl and validatableProperties as well, which can't be done in an extension. I'm beginning to think this solution may be the best available due to some inheritance flaws with Swift.

Comment: You’re right. Extensions can’t override the existing methods, but you can swizzle existing methods. Please search for method swizzling in swift.

Comment: If anyone googles their way here: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f

First I've heard of good ol swizzle.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I believe it is the closest implementation possible to what is needed, due to inheritance limitations in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of ValidationView when you instantiate CustomTextField.

Something like this:

```swift
@IBDesignable open class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var validationView: ValidationView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.validationView = ValidationView()
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not make the CustomTextField a ValidationView. It means I'd need to add the ValidationView instance as a subview, which isn't inheritance really.